# How to get GST APIs direct access from government portal

Tags: gsp

How to get GST APIs direct access from government portal. I don't want to go with any GSP. GSTIN is eligible to call GST APIs and how to generate clientId and clientSecret to call GST APIs.

I have e-invoicing clientId and clientSecret but it is not working in GST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

While direct access to GST APIs from the government portal is not currently available without a GSP, here's the process for accessing them through a GSP:

1. Choose a GSP (GST Suvidha Provider):

Select a GSP that suits your needs from the list of authorized GSPs on the GST portal.
Consider factors like pricing, features, and integration capabilities.
2. Register on the GSP's Portal:

Create an account on the chosen GSP's portal.
Provide your GSTIN and other required details.
3. Enable API Access on the GST Portal:

Log in to the GST portal using your GSTIN.
Navigate to the "My Profile" section.
Under "Quick Links," select "Manage API Access."
Click "Yes" to enable API access.
Choose the duration for which API access should be enabled.
Confirm your selection.
4. Obtain Client ID and Client Secret from the GSP:

The GSP will provide you with a Client ID and Client Secret.
These credentials are specific to your GSTIN and the GSP you've chosen.
5. Use the Credentials in API Calls:

Integrate the Client ID and Client Secret into your application or software to make API calls to the GST system.
The GSP will handle the communication between your application and the GST portal.

Comment: Can you suggest any reliable and cost effective GSPs?